# ¿Cómo comparar fecha inicial y fecha final?

Tags: javascript, html5, date

Quiero comparar dos fechas, una fecha inicial y una fecha final. La fecha inicial debe ser menor a la fecha final. No deseo un evento alert, quiero mostrar el mensaje en el campo fecha final cuando esa fecha sea menor, similar los mensajes requiere="" de html5. Este es mi código:

```js
function validate() {
inicio=document.getElementById('fechaInicial').value;
fin=document.getElementById('fechaFinal').value;
if(fin<inicial) 
document.getElementById('fechaFinal').setCustomValidity('Esta fecha ser mayor a fecha incial.');
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="" name="form"'>
Desde:<input name="fechaInicial" type="date" placeholder="" required="" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
Hasta:<input name="fechaFinal" type="date" title="La fecha inicial debe ser menor que la fecha final" required="" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" oninput="validate()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes bastantes problemas con las comillas. Además, no les has indicado los ID's a ninguno de tus `inputs`.

Por otro lado, tendrías que comparar con respecto a `inicio` y no a la variable `inicial`, la cual no está definida.

Y por último, para que el atributo `title` se cambie cuando la condición sea incorrecta, debes reescribir su valor accediendo directamente al valor de `title`:

```js
function validate() {
inicio=document.getElementById('fechaInicial').value;
fin=document.getElementById('fechaFinal').value;
if(fin<inicio) 
document.getElementById('fechaFinal').title ='Esta fecha ser mayor a fecha incial.';
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="" name="form">
Desde:<input id="fechaInicial" name="fechaInicial" type="date" placeholder="" required="" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
Hasta:<input id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" type="date" title="La fecha inicial debe ser menor que la fecha final" required="" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" oninput="validate()">
</form>
```

Comment: Disculpa, tienes razón se me fue comilla doble junto con una comilla sencilla, además no le coloque el id a los inputs, respecto al alert quiero que se muestre como en html5 cambiando el setCustomValidity()

Comment: @JairoCarballo a que te refieres con:** quiero que se muestre como en html5 cambiando el setCustomValidity()**

Comment: @rn3w Justo iba a preguntar yo lo mismo.

Comment: Quiero que cuando la fecha final sea menor no me muestre un alert sino me muestre el title""

Comment: Algo así: Desde<input id="fechaInicial" name="fechaInicial" type="date" required="" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
Hasta:<input id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" type="date" title="La fecha final debe ser mayor" required="" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" oninput="if(this.checkValidity()) form.fechaInicial.value > this.value ? this.title : '');">

Comment: @JairoCarballo ¿El título de la página? ¿O que en el input salga un title?

Comment: del input que diga  title="La fecha final debe ser mayor"

Comment: @JairoCarballo Ahora he entendido tu pregunta. Ya he editado mi respuesta. Ahora funciona correctamente.

Comment: No me muestra el title. será que le falta algo más?

Comment: @JairoCarballo Ah, ¿quieres que se muestre automáticamente? Ahora mismo se muestra pasando por encima del input.

Comment: Ah si ya lo vi, lo que quiero es que se muestre similar a cuando el campo es requerido y se deja vacío o cuando no se cumple un patter se muestre el title, por eso creo que se podía hacer con setCustomValidity() cambiando validationMessage el cual hace algo similar. Pero aún no doy con la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Listo, esto era lo que quería:

```js
<script>
function validate() {
 if(document.getElementById('fechaFinal').value<document.getElementById('fechaInicial').value) 
  document.getElementById('fechaFinal').setCustomValidity('Esta fecha debe ser mayor a la fecha inicial');
 else 
  document.getElementById('fechaFinal').setCustomValidity('');
}
</script>
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="" name="form">
Desde:<input id="fechaInicial" name="fechaInicial" type="date" placeholder="" required="" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
Hasta:<input id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" type="date" title="La fecha inicial debe ser menor que la fecha final" required="" max="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" oninput="validate()">
<button>Enviar</button> 
</form>
```